# search word existence in mysql database with ~2 Mio rows

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, cartesian-product

I'm programming a small mobile keyboard based on the old T9 text input technology. Well my program calculates the cartesian product of all possible combinations and it checks in each iteration for the existence of a specific word before continuing due to math complexity.

Example for word 'HELLO' by typing [4][3][5][5][6]:

```
Input [4] => ['G', 'H', 'I']
    are there words in DB which starts with g%, h% or i%?
Input [4] [3] => ['GE', 'HE', ..]
    are there words in DB which starts with ge%, he%?
Input [4] [3] [5] => ['GEL', 'HEL', ...]
    are there words in DB which starts with gel%, hel%?
Input [4] [3] [5] [5] => ['HELL', ...]
    are there words in DB which starts with hell%?
Input [4] [3] [5] [5] [6] => ['HELLO', 'GEKKO', ...]
    are there words in DB which starts with hello%, gekko%?
...
```

The program works fine and outputs only the cartesian product with existing words. But the database table has ~2 million words which makes a full-text search like `SELECT * FROM words_en WHERE name LIKE 'hel%'` super 
sluggish. A simple lookup like above take about 10 seconds which make my program impractical.

Splitting the table into 26 sub-tables for each alphabetical character one helps a little bit but is still not practical with 2-5 seconds for each lookup.

What can I do to optimize simple word existence lookups in mysql?

Don't know T9 text input?
Here is a client sided implementation: https://www.sainsmograf.com/labs/t9-emulator/

Comment: You have millions of records and don't use an index? Unbelievable.

Comment: I am not expert but when I was using MySQL full text index, my query was something like this WHERE match(table_column) against (p_SearchText).... and doing so was hitting full text index.  Moved to Lucene search which provides similar or better performance.  Try adding full text index on 'note' column and then match ... against to see if it makes a difference.